# NE tags in NLTK ConllCorpusReader

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm trying to use CoNLLCorpusReader for CoNLL2003 dataset. This dataset contains 4 columns (example):

```html
WORD      POS   CHUNK NE
U.N.      NNP   I-NP  I-ORG
official  NN    I-NP  O
Ekeus     NNP   I-NP  I-PER
heads     VBZ   I-VP  O
for       IN    I-PP  O
Baghdad   NNP   I-NP  I-LOC
.         .     O     O
```

I create corpus and it works - I can get words, sents and tuples with pos tags and chunk tags.

The question is, how can i get Named Entity tags from my corpus? I know there is corpus.raw() method, but is there really no way to get it with something like corpus.iob_words()? I found this issue: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/63, but in the latest version of this corpusReader there are no additional arguments in iob_words method that I can use to change the list of columns I want to get.

Comment: Hohoho the old issue #63 haunting us again... There's a workaround but I don't like it. The principle way to resolve this is to rewrite/extend the CoNLL corpus reader to read unspecified no. of columns.

Comment: Looking at the code, it already reads an unspecified number of columns! It just doesn't have an interface for selecting columns ad hoc.

Comment: Cool! Thanks @alexis for pointing that out. Didn't know about that. Now lets get your answers into the codebase!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like may have to help yourself. Give this a try, I *think* it is all you need to extend `ConllCorpusReader` so that `iob_words()` can be told to select the `NE` column instead of the (default) `CHUNK` column. `iob_sents()` `chunked_words()` and `chunked_sents()` ought to be similarly modified.

```
class betterConllReader(ConllCorpusReader):

    def iob_words(self, fileids=None, tagset=None, column="chunk"):
        """
        :return: a list of word/tag/IOB tuples
        :rtype: list(tuple)
        :param fileids: the list of fileids that make up this corpus
        :type fileids: None or str or list
        """
        self._require(self.WORDS, self.POS, self.CHUNK)
        def get_iob_words(grid):
            return self._get_iob_words(grid, tagset, column)
        return LazyConcatenation(LazyMap(get_iob_words, self._grids(fileids)))

    def _get_iob_words(self, grid, tagset=None, column="chunk"):
        pos_tags = self._get_column(grid, self._colmap['pos'])
        if tagset and tagset != self._tagset:
            pos_tags = [map_tag(self._tagset, tagset, t) for t in pos_tags]
        return list(zip(self._get_column(grid, self._colmap['words']), pos_tags,
                   self._get_column(grid, self._colmap[column])))
```

All I did was replace the hardcoded `"chunk"` with a keyword argument. With a little more work, multiple columns could be selected (reasonable with `iob_*()`, less clearly so for the `chunked_*()` variants.)

Comment: Yeah, thank you! I've decided to create new class too and wrote a new .get_all_tags() method that returns all 4 components, actually, just copy-pasted .iob_words() and added NE column in returned list.

Comment: @alexis, nltk has created a PR for this. Would you mind taking a look and help give some suggestions/reviews? https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/1966#issue-171312566

Comment: @alvas, DO NOT approve the pull request, it's plainly the wrong way to do this. I'll comment on the PR this weekend.

Comment: Thank you @alexis!

Comment: Done. But really, what were you thinking? Did you look at the patch?